# How can I automate creation of a list of vectors containing simulated data from a known distribution, using a "for loop" in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector, random

First stack exchange post so please bear with me. I'm trying to automate the creation of a list, and the list will be made up of many empty vectors of various, known lengths. The empty vectors will then be filled with simulated data. How can I automate creation of this list using a for loop in R?

In this simplified example, fish have been caught by casting a net 4 times, and their abundance is given in the vector "abundance" (from counting the number of total fish in each net). We don't have individual fish weights, just the mean weight of all fish each net, so I need to simulate their weights from a lognormal distribution. So, I'm then looking to fill those empty vectors for each net, each with a length equal to the number of fish caught in that net, with weight data simulated from a lognormal distribution with a known mean and standard deviation.

A simplified example of my code:

```
abundance <- c(5, 10, 9, 20)
net1 <- rep(NA, abundance[1])
net2 <- rep(NA, abundance[2])
net3 <- rep(NA, abundance[3])
net4 <- rep(NA, abundance[4])

simulated_weights <- list(net1, net2, net3, net4)

#meanlog vector for each net
weight_per_net

#meansd vector for each net
sd_per_net

for (i in 1:4) {
  simulated_weights[[i]] <- rlnorm(n = abundance[i], meanlog = weight_per_net[i], sd = sd_per_net[i])
  print(simulated_weights_VM)
}
```

Could anyone please help me automate this so that I don't have to write out each net vector (e.g. net1) by hand, and then also write out all the net names in the list() function? There are far more nets than 4 so it would be extremely time consuming and inefficient to do it this way. I've tried several things from other posts like paste0(), other for loops, as.list(c()), all to no avail.

Thanks!
HM

Comment: I would suggest not creating all those `net` variables in the first place. If you have a bunch of varaiable names with sequential numbers (indexes) in them, that usually means you are not doing things in a very R like way. Better to keep them in a list in the first place. For example you could instead do `net <- lapply(abundance, function(x) rep(NA, x))` to get the same values but in a way that's much easier to work with in R.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did wonder if I could get around that intermediate step--lapply worked beautifully and quickly. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah thank you Ronak for letting me know about that! Will do, and now I'll know for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you don't need the `net1`, `net2`, etc variables at all. You can just do

```
abundance <- c(5, 10, 9, 20)
simulated_weights <- lapply(abundance, function(x) rep(NA, x))
```

The `lapply` function will return the list you need by calling the function once for each value of `abundance`

Answer (score 0):

We could create the 'simulated_weights' with `split` and `rep`

```
simulated_weights <- split(rep(rep(NA, length(abundance)), abundance),  
            rep(seq_along(abundance), abundance))
```